# Diameter of a subset of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(\Bbb R,d)$ be the metric space with the metric function

$$d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1 + |x-y|}\;. $$

Calculate $\operatorname{diam}(0,\infty)$.

I am thinking the answer is $1$ because

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{1+x}=1\;.$$

Is the answers and my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, the diameter is $1$ for the reason that you give.

Comment: But I would say you need more reasoning to show why that computation is the diameter of the set.  In particular, why not explicitly use the definition of "diameter", instead of leaving it to the reader to guess how your computation relates to it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Intuitively yes! But one needs to show that for all $x,y\in (0,\infty)$, $d(x,y)\leq 1$ and for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $x,y \in (0,\infty)$ such that $d(x,y)>1-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subset (X,d)$  a metric space. $$\text{diam}(A):=\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}.$$

In this case, $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ is the metric specified by  $\displaystyle d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$.

$A=(0,\infty)$. Since the metric is obviously bounded (why?), we know that the diameter of any non-empty subset is finite because $1$ is an upper bound.

We suspect that $\text{diam}(A)=1$. Thus we need to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a pair $(x,y)$ in $A$ such that $d(x,y)>1-\epsilon$. (Why? Think about the definition of supremum.)

If $\epsilon > 1$, there is nothing to show because $A$ is non-empty.

If $\epsilon \leq 1$, we choose $\displaystyle x=1$ and $\displaystyle y=\frac{2}{\epsilon}$.

Then you should be able to show that $d(x,y)>1-\epsilon$.